# Cannot read property 'type' of undefined Occurred while linting In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three components App, Guest, User. I am checking condition(App.js) if it true then User component will render otherwise Guest component. I am getting Error. Error is Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
Occurred while linting  How to solve this.

```
*Index.html*
<title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>


**Index.js**

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
ReactDOM.render(<App consumer= {true} />,document.getElementById('root'));


**App.js**

import React, {Component} from 'react'
import User from './User.js'
import Guest from './Guest.js'

export default class App extends Component{
    render(){
        const varify = this.props.consumer;
        if (varify) {
          return <User />;
        }
    return <Guest />;
     }
}

 **User.js**

import React, {Component} from 'react'

export default class User extends Component{
    render(){
    return(
        <div>
        <h1> Welcome </h1>
        <button>Log out</button>
        </div>
    );
}
}

**Guest.js**

mport React, {Component} from'react'

export default class Guest extends  Component {
    render (){
        return (
            <div>
            <h1>Welcome Guest</h1>
            <button>Login</button>
         <button>Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        );
    
}
}
```

Comment: In `<App />`, in your return function, simply do a conditional render: `return({this.props.consumer ? <User /> : <Guest />)}`

Comment: the only problem i see is the missing `i` in the `import` statement in **Guest.js**. Otherwise your [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-wilson-bztss) seems to be working fine.

Comment: Oh, I missed that i while copying from Code editor to here. That i is there in my original code. It is working now as I close the browser and start again.

Comment: your code is working here too besides the I from import. what is the exact error code and line?

Comment: Now code is working after I close browser and start again.